# How to add images before Header on exporting Data in Kartik Export Menu>

Tags: kartik-v

I am trying to add an image on as logo before headers in excel and pdf using ExportMenu by Kartik but unable to do so. I was successful in adding an image by using grid view and added images by passing  in the table header and td so when exporting the grid, the image was prepended. But I am unable to do a Similar thing in ExportMenu and I am using ExportMenu by Kartik because exporting content from gridview was an issue because it had to load all the data on the page and it took a lot of time. So for a smaller number of records, it was working fine but for a larger number like 100k+, exporting gridview was not an ideal solution. Even right now, it is taking time for 1000+ records although I am using pagination and using batch tool of Kartik. So I am in need of a Solution on how to export images before the header (I Used contentBefore aswell but it doesn't allow images but string values only - https://demos.krajee.com/export). Any idea or help would be much appreciated